# PORT=5000 react-scripts start 'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, localhost, port

Testing on Windows-

I have a React frontend running on default localhost:3000 and I need to also run the admin on localhost:5000  but when I npm start admin, I get:

react-admin@0.1.0 start

> PORT=5000 react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have admin .env
`REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000`

frontend .env
`REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000 REACT_APP_ADMIN_URL=http://localhost:5000 REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost`

How can I get admin to compile/ load and specify it port 5000?

in admin - in package.json tried changing-
"start": "react-scripts start",
instead of "start": "PORT=5000 react-scripts start",
This gets-
Something is already running on port 3000.
Would you like to run the app on another port instead? ... yes  .. loads on localhost:3001

Loads the page but does not function (can't log in)

tried changing
"start": "PORT=5000 react-scripts start",
to
"start": "PORT=5000 && react-scripts start",
Does not load

Comment: Either use `cross-env` or a different terminal like git bash

Comment: Tried running the admin npm from git bash but still got the port error.  installed npm install --save-dev cross-env     ..but still error, is there more set up for cross-env?

Answer (score 1):

in package.json file find this, [image]

then change that to this, [image]

"start": "react-scripts start",  issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

fixed by:

admin>  edit: package.json

changing- "start": "PORT=5000 react-scripts start"  to  "start": "react-scripts start"

save

and edit admin> .env -to look like this:

PORT=5000

REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000

save

admin> npm start

Admin page now loads on http://localhost:5000/
and log in working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).